# Truncate Head in paragraph/label in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uilabel, truncate

[image]While truncating a string with multiple lines in a label, the `lineBreakMode` with `byTruncatingHead` only works on the last line instead of the initial line. Is there any way to get around this?

So if the text is

`"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."`

and the `numberOfLines` is 2 then the expected outcome is

`... versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).`

Instead of

`It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content by accident,`

and in the second line

`... sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).`

Comment: So you want to truncate head, not tail?

Comment: Select 'Truncate Head' from the Line Break drop-down menu.

Comment: @aheze yes, i want to truncate head and not the tail.

Comment: @ElTomato I did that and if there are multiple lines of texts, only the last line's head gets truncated instead of the first.